# Maintain proper nouns and capitalised words while stemming

Tags: python, nlp, porter-stemmer

I am designing a text processing program and need to stem the words for exploratory analysis later. One of my processes is to stem the words and I have to use Porter Stemmer.

I have designed a DataFrame structure to store my data. Furthermore, I have also designed a function to apply to the DataFrame. When I apply the function to the DataFrame, the stemming works but it does not keep the capitalised (or proper nouns) words.

A snippet of my code:

```
from nltk.stem.porter import PorterStemmer

def stemming(word):
    stemmer = PorterStemmer()
    word = str(word)
    if word.title():
        stemmer.stem(word).capitalize()
    elif word.isupper():
        stemmer.stem(word).upper()
    else:
        stemmer.stem(word)
    return word

dfBody['body'] = dfBody['body'].apply(lambda x: [stemming(y) for y in x])
```

This is my result with that has no capitalised words:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mgza6.png)

Sample of dataset (my dataset is very large):

```
file    body
PP3169 ['performing', 'Maker', 'USA', 'computer', 'Conference', 'NIPS']
```

Expected output (after applying stemming function):

```
file    body
PP3169 ['perform', 'Make', 'USA', 'comput', 'Confer', 'NIPS']
```

Any advice will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you please share a few lines from the dataframe as a small example/test data so we could test on that? Thank you.

Comment: shouldn't be with `word = ` - ie. `word = stemmer.stem(word).capitalize()`

Comment: @furas that turns the first letter of every word capital :S

Comment: Can you give an example of input and corresponding output you expect, when you say capitalised (or proper nouns)  these can be 2 different cases

Comment: `word.title()` converts text to title. You have to compare `if word == word.title():`, or check `if word[0].isupper() and word[1:].islower()`

Comment: @furas u can add it as a answer I have deleted mine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: you should assing result to `word`

```
word = stemmer.stem(word).capitalize()
```

Second: `word.title()` doesn't check if word is capitalized but it creates capitalized word so you should check

```
if word == word.title():
```

eventually

```
if word[0].isupper() and word[1:].islower():
```

---

```
def stemming(word):
    stemmer = PorterStemmer()
    word = str(word)
    if word == word.title():
        word = stemmer.stem(word).capitalize()
    elif word.isupper():
        word = stemmer.stem(word).upper()
    else:
        word = stemmer.stem(word)
    return word
```